# Apache Beam ETL dimension table loading , any example?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am thinking of Loading File into one Dimension table. My solution is:

1. Beam.read the file
2. Create the side input from the DB about existing data.
3. in a ParDo: filter the records which are already in the side input
4. biquerySink into DB.

and want to inquire if someone has implement this ? and can you give me some example for this ?
Thanks

```
can you give me some example about coGroupByKey. I understand that it may look like below : Sorry,I am newbie to Dataflow,and watching codes is the best way to me 

step 1: sourcedata = beam.ReadFromText(...)
step 2: existing_table = beam.pvalue.AsDict(p
                                    | beam.Read(beam.BigQuerySource(my_query)
                                    | beam.Map(format_rows)

I assume the structure of sourcedata and existing data is the same :<k,v>                       
step 3:  source_existing_Data=  {sourcedata,existing_table}
                                |'coGroupBy' >> beam.coGroupByKey()


step4:  new_Data = source_existing_Data | beam.filter(lamada (name,(existing,source)):source is NONE))

step 5:  bigQuerySink(new_Data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For the row coming from the text file and row coming form BIGQUERY needed to be done with function :
    from GCPUtil import BuildTupleRowFn as BuildTupleRowFn
    from GCPUtil import BuildDictTupleRowFn as BuildDictTupleRowFn
and also the new data also after coGroupKey and Filter also need to convert since what get from coGroupKey is Tuple, so need to convert it from Dict or List.

Below is the detailed codes:

#####################################################################
#   Develop by Emma 2017/08/19
#####################################################################

    import argparse
    import logging
    from random import randrange

    import apache_beam as beam

    from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
    from apache_beam.pvalue import AsList
    from apache_beam.pvalue import AsSingleton
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
    import sys
    sys.path.append("..")
    from GCPUtil import BuildTupleRowFn as BuildTupleRowFn
    from GCPUtil import BuildDictTupleRowFn as BuildDictTupleRowFn

    def configure_bigquery_write():
        return [
            ('CAND_ID', 'STRING'),
            ('CAND_NAME', 'STRING'),
        ]


    class BuildRowFn(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            row = {}
            for entry in element:
                print('start')
                print(entry)
                # print(entry[0])
                # print(entry[1])
                print('end')
                row['CAND_ID'] = entry[0]
                row['CAND_NAME'] = entry[1]
                yield row



    def run(argv=None):
        """Run the workflow."""

        # schema = 'CAND_ID:STRING,CAND_NAME:STRING'
        schema = 'CAND_ID:STRING,CAND_NAME:STRING'
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--input', default=r'd:/resource/test*')
        parser.add_argument('--output', default=r'd:/output/test/new_emma')

        # parser.add_argument('--project', default='chinarose_project')
        known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
        pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DirectRunner'
        pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = 'chinarose_project'
        # query = 'select store FROM [chinarose_project:emma_test.sales]'
        query = 'select CAND_ID ,CAND_NAME from emma_test.campaign'
        p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

        # get the length of the word and write them in the text file,noticed the UDF

        source_data = (p | beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
                       | beam.Map(lambda a: a.split(","))
                       | beam.ParDo(BuildTupleRowFn())
                       )
        # source_data | 'write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)
        # source_data | WriteToText(known_args.output)


        print("connect to BQ")
        existing_data= (p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, project='chinarose_project'))
                          | beam.ParDo(BuildDictTupleRowFn())

                        )
        #existing_data | WriteToText(known_args.output)

        source_existing_data = ((source_data, existing_data)
                                | 'GoGroupBy' >> beam.CoGroupByKey())

        # source_existing_data |'write to text' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)
        new_data = (source_existing_data | beam.Filter(lambda (name, (source, existing)): len(existing) == 0)
                    | beam.Map(lambda (name, (source, existing)): [(name, s) for s in source])
                    | beam.ParDo(BuildRowFn())
                    | beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(table='campaign_emma_v2',  dataset='emma_test',project='chinarose_project',schema=schema))
                    )

        #new_data | 'write to text' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)


        p.run().wait_until_finish()

      if __name__ == '__main__':
        # logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
        print('begin')
        run()
        print('end')
```

Answer (score 1):

Side inputs are a good option for this, but consider that if your DB table is pretty large, you may find later that `CoGroupByKey` is a better option. To implement this in side inputs, you'd do the following:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(..)
existing_table = beam.pvalue.AsDict(p
                                    | beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(my_query)
                                    | beam.Map(format_rows))

class FilterRowsDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, elem, table_dict):
    k = elem[0]
    if k not in table_dict:
      yield elem

result = (p
          | beam.ReadFromText(...)
          | beam.ParDo(FilterRowsDoFn(), table_dict=existing_table))
```

And then you can write the result to BQ. But, again, if your table already contains many elements, you may want to consider using `CoGroupByKey`.

---

The code to accomplish this using CoGroupByKey should look something like this:

```
sourcedata = (p 
              | beam.ReadFromText(...)
              | beam.Map(format_text))
existing_table = (p
                  | beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(my_query)
                  | beam.Map(format_rows))

source_existing_data = ((sourcedata, existing_table)
                        | 'coGroupBy' >> beam.coGroupByKey())

new_data = (source_existing_data 
            | beam.Filter(lamada (name, (source, existing)): not list(source))
            | beam.FlatMap(lambda (name, (source, existing)): [(name, s) for s in source]))

result = new_data | bigQuerySink(new_Data)
```

Let me know if you have any trouble using either of the code snippets so I'll fix them up.

Comment: Pablo-  can please take a provide an example code of coGroupByKey, and see my answer in below ? Thank you..

Comment: I've edited my question to use both approaches. It's very similar to what you propose, but with a few differences. Hope it helps : )

Comment: Pablo --Thank you a lot for your patience,I will definitely try it. ：）

Comment: Pablo- for :beam.FlatMap(lambda (name, (source, existing)): [(name, s) for s in source])) ,should  I use beam.Map instead of beam.FlatMap? or flatMAp normally used at the last step to return the pcollection

Comment: Map should receive a single element output. Flatmap receives an iterable object. We're using Flatmap because that way, each element in the list will be added to the pcollection

Comment: Pablo--I have tried your suggestions. and post my answer in below,and run it in my PC, : and for new_data = (source_existing_data | beam.Filter(lambda (name, (source, existing)): len(existing) == 0) I use len(existing)=0 instead of not list(source),I assume the new data is from the source,,and feel free to edit it for any improvement.Thanks !

Comment: you can edit my post yourself if you'd like! : ) - if not, I'll edit it tomorrow.